# Why would a company start their e-mail subject line with a space?

Tags: email

I've just scratched my head, then screamed to the screen about a bug for a few hours. It turned out that a company was sending e-mails to me with subject lines such as:

```
 Your order 213434563 is ready!
```

That is, with a single space in the beginning. As you can imagine, I was checking for subjects beginning with "Your order ", when I needed to do " Your order " or modify the subject lines, which I would rather not.

What could be the reason for this? Is this an attempt to "stand out slightly" or something? It almost seems on purpose to mess with my script's logic...

It really annoys me to think that somebody could have made a business script where they randomly accidentally added a space in front and never spotted it...

PS: And to make it clear, this is a company which I have an established relationship with. Not some random SPAM e-mail.

Comment: As there's no reason for this it's likely accidental. Such a mistake is easy to make, but hard to spot (as you have proved in this question).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. Just trim all leading and trailing spaces.
However the best approach would be to switch to a REST based API instead of using email. Ask the company you have as partner if they have a REST API or similar.